# Ссылка на поиск Google по заголовку вопроса в шаблоне

Tags: предложение

Очень надоедает каждый раз вручную переписывать в адресной строке 
`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946668/формат-даты-php`

на

`site:ru.stackoverflow.com формат даты php`

плюс это тупо дольше, чем очередному шустриле накропать 100500-й ответ на один и тот же вопрос.

Так что готовая ссылка была бы очень кстати. Могу даже подарить шаблон:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com+{заголовок вопроса}
```

*Пояснение для слабо представляющих себе технологию Stack Overflow:* на сайтах платформы существует такое правило, что вопросы-дубликаты должны закрываться с формулировкой "Этот вопрос уже задан и имеет решение".

Однако платформа не предоставляет никаких инструментов, которые помогали бы найти похожий вопрос, который уже был задан. Встроенный поиск, который выводит "Похожие" вопросы в боковой панели, ищет что угодно, только не дубликаты.

Google Search, в свою очередь, находит дубликаты прекрасно.

Таким образом, добавление ссылки на поиск Google по заголовку вопроса на сайте ru.stackoverflow.com сильно облегчит задачу закрытия дубликатов.

Без наличия такого рода инструментов можно сколько угодно причитать про пиратские сайты и проповедовать про междупланетную базу знаний, но в реальности сайт Stack Overflow На Русском так и останется конвейером по зарабатыванию бессмысленных циферок "репутации" путем торопливых ответов на примитивные вопросы.

Comment: Мышкой наверх, а сайт не нужен обычно, ну или можно руками дописать. (Минус не мой).

Comment: Про сайт не нужен обычно лучше убрать реплику, не позориться

Comment: Возможно было бы лучше просто добавить поиск по сайту с помощью гугловской поисковой машины

Comment: Так если это для закрытия как дубликата надо, так и предлагай в окно поиска дубликата добавлять, на странице-то нафига такая кнопка?

Comment: Такое на MSE нужно предлагать.

Comment: В "похожие" вопросы в боковой панели попадают вопросы с такими же словами в заголовке (может, метки еще тоже учитываются). Т.е. похожи там на самом деле не вопросы, а заголовки.